# How do I Share Enum values between my Java code and .proto file

Tags: java, enums, protocol-buffers

I have a class that I wish to protobuf. in that class one of the fields is an enum (in a class of it's own). Can I avoid defining an identical enum value in my .proto file ? Or will I have to manually make sure the enum definition in the java code is the same as in the .proto file?

java code:

```
public enum Location {
UNDEF(0),HOME(1), WORK(2);
...
}
```

.proto file corresponding code:

```
message Address{
    enum location {
        UNDEF = 0;
        HOME = 1;
        WORK = 2;
    }
   optional location addressLocation;
...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protocol Buffers: How to make .proto file for enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119308/protocol-buffers-how-to-make-proto-file-for-enum)

Comment: @TharinduKumara: my question was asked 3 years ago. The question you set as duplicate is just 1 day old. I'm the original askee, not the duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution for keeping things like this in sync is often code generation; determine which of your definitions is the Single Point of Truth, and create the others from it. Protocol Buffers has [built-in support for Java code generation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#enum) with nifty features like automatically handling duplicate enum values.