# Protocol Buffers: How to make .proto file for enum?

Tags: java, enums, protocol-buffers, grpc

My enum in java looks like this(mentioned below). What it would be in .proto? Not able to figure out how to take care of constructor and Getter methods for the variables (type and code).

```
public enum PaxType {
    ADULT("ADT", 'A'),
    CHILD("CNN", 'C'),
    INFANT("IFT", 'I');

    private String type;
    private char   code;

    PaxType(String type, char code) {
        this.type = type;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public char getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Share Enum values between my Java code and .proto file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130965/how-do-i-share-enum-values-between-my-java-code-and-proto-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer and some further investigation here a full working example.

assume following files in the current directory

```
PaxTypeEnum.proto
TestProtobufEnum.java
// https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases
protoc-3.1.0-linux-x86_64.zip
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java
protobuf-java-3.1.0.jar
```

**PaxTypeEnum.proto**

```
syntax = "proto2";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

message EnumProto {
  extend google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
    optional string name = 50000;
    optional string singleCharCode = 50001;
  }

  enum PaxType {
    ADULT = 0 [(name) = "ADT", (singleCharCode) = 'A'];
    CHILD = 1 [(name) = "CNN", (singleCharCode) = 'C'];
    INFANT = 2 [(name) = "IFT", (singleCharCode) = 'I'];
  }
}
```

**TestProtobufEnum.java**

```
import com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos;
import com.google.protobuf.Descriptors;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class TestProtobufEnum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PaxTypeEnum.EnumProto.PaxType CHILD =.
            PaxTypeEnum.EnumProto.PaxType.CHILD;

        System.out.println("get fields dynamically for PaxType.CHILD");
        Set<Map.Entry<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object>> allFields =.
            CHILD.getValueDescriptor().getOptions().getAllFields().entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> entry : allFields){
            System.out.printf("field: descriptor: %-14s  value: %s%n",
                    entry.getKey().getName(),
                    entry.getValue()
            );
        }

        System.out.println("get fields statically");
        PaxTypeEnum.EnumProto.PaxType[] paxTypes =.
                PaxTypeEnum.EnumProto.PaxType.values();
        for (PaxTypeEnum.EnumProto.PaxType value : paxTypes) {
            DescriptorProtos.EnumValueOptions options =.
                    value.getValueDescriptor().getOptions();
            System.out.printf("PaxType: %-6s  name: %s  singleCharCode: %s%n",
                    value.toString(),
                    options.getExtension(PaxTypeEnum.EnumProto.name),
                    options.getExtension(PaxTypeEnum.EnumProto.singleCharCode)
            );
        }

    }
}
```

1. unzip `protoc-3.1.0-linux-x86_64.zip` in current directory
2. set environment variables

   ```
   PROTO_HOME=$(pwd)
   PATH=${PROTO_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
   ```
3. generate the Java source from the `*.proto` file

   ```
   protoc PaxTypeEnum.proto --java_out=. --proto_path=${PROTO_HOME}/include:.
   ```
4. compile the Java demo

   ```
   javac -cp .:protobuf-java-3.1.0.jar TestProtobufEnum.java
   ```
5. run the Java demo

   ```
   java -cp .:protobuf-java-3.1.0.jar TestProtobufEnum
   ```

output

```
get fields dynamically for PaxType.CHILD
field: descriptor: name            value: CNN
field: descriptor: singleCharCode  value: C

get fields statically
PaxType: ADULT   name: ADT  singleCharCode: A
PaxType: CHILD   name: CNN  singleCharCode: C
PaxType: INFANT  name: IFT  singleCharCode: I
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what the meaning of the numbers is 50000 and 50001?
Trying to understand those numbers, thanks

Comment: @skal The numbers are the field numbers which uniquely identify the field in the encoding. For more information have a look into the documentation https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#assigning_field_numbers.

Answer (score 4):

There is not any recommended way to represent java enum classes. But you can follow something like below.

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
  optional string type= 51234;
  optional string code= 51235;
}

enum PaxType {
  ADULT = 0 [(type) = "ADT", (code) = 'A'];
  CHILD = 1 [(type) = "CNN", (code) = 'C'];
  INFANT = 2 [(type) = "IFT", (code) = 'I']
}
```

The annotation is accessed through the `EnumValueDescriptor` interface.

Comment: can you elaborate on what the meaning of the numbers is 51234 and 51235? Trying to understand those numbers, thanks